# java static variable inheritance - how to improve code?

Tags: java

I have some classes like these:

```
class  resourceA
{
    public static String ResPath="c:/somethingA";

    private double [] data;

    public void load(String fileName)
    {
        //Load data[] from ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }

    public void save(String fileName)
    {
        //Save data[] to ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }

    public static String [] list()
    {
        return (new File(ResPath)).list(); 
    }
}
```

.

```
class  resourceB
{
    public static String ResPath="c:/somethingB";

    private int [] data;

    public void load(String fileName)
    {
        //Load data[] from ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }

    public void save(String fileName)
    {
        //Save data[] to ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }

    public static String [] list()
    {
        return (new java.io.File(ResPath)).list(); 
    }
}
```

And 3 more similar classes. Note that each class has private **data** of different types, so **save()** and **load()** are specific for them.

So I wanted to write less code using inheritance like this:

```
class abstract resourceGeneric
{
    public static String ResPath="c:/somethingB";

    public abstract void load(String fileName);

    public abstract void save(String fileName);

    public static String [] list()
    {
        return (new java.io.File(ResPath)).list(); 
    }

}

class resourceA extends resourceGeneric
{
    private double [] data;

    public void load(String fileName)
    {
        //Load data[] from ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }

    public void save(String fileName)
    {
        //Save data[] to ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }
}

class resourceB extends resourceGeneric
{
    private int [] data;

    public void load(String fileName)
    {
        //Load data[] from ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }

    public void save(String fileName)
    {
        //Save data[] to ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }
}
```

Same for other 3 classes.

This would prevent rewritting the same **list()** method for every class and at the same time having a kind of common interface or behavior (all inherited classes would have to implement **load()** and **save()** methods)

Everything looked fine, but I got an error when I executed this:

```
resourceA.ResPath="A";
resourceB.ResPath="B";
resourceA.list();
```

In this case, **resourceA.list()** is searching files in "B" instead "A". Because **ResPath** is a static variable of parent class **resourceGeneric**.

I could declare **ResPath** for each class, but in this case **resourceGeneric.list()** could not know which is the path (code is not compilable)

Since this didn't work as intended, I would like to have suggestions on how to fix it or how to write a better code for my original classes, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you're posting above suggests that only one class with a non-static resPath variable would be best, but this is based on my limited understanding of your problem and your actual *real* code. Are just the paths different? Or are all the methods completely and innately different?

Comment: Why don't use Generics? So you can create a resourceA class with data type you need, different to the resourceB data type.
This should help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow this structure for classes then don't declare `ResPath` static and have its value set in one of implementing class constructors like this:

```
class abstract resourceGeneric
{
    protected String ResPath;    // Dont declare ResPath static
    public abstract void load(String fileName);
    public abstract void save(String fileName);

    public static String [] list()
    {
        return (new java.io.File(ResPath)).list(); 
    }
}
```

Then base classes can be like:

```
class resourceA extends resourceGeneric
{
    private double [] data;

    public resourceA(String resPath){ 
        this.ResPath = respath;
    }

    public void load(String fileName)
    {
        //Load data[] from ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }

    public void save(String fileName)
    {
        //Save data[] to ResPath+"/"+fileName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the static variable is a pointer to a single location in your abstract class, what you're doing with

```
resourceA.ResPath="A";
resourceB.ResPath="B";
resourceA.list();
```

is essentially setting the same location in memory twice. resourceA.ResPath and resourceB.ResPath point to the *same* location in memory.

Static variables are generally discouraged, as is accessing and modifying public variables. But if you want to keep to that approach, here's a suggestion.

```
class abstract resourceGeneric
{
    private static List<String> ResPaths=new ArrayList<String>();
    private String ResPath;

    public abstract void load(String fileName);

    public abstract void save(String fileName);

    public void setResPath(String ResPath) 
    {
        ResPaths.add(ResPath);
        this.ResPath = ResPath;    
    }

    public static String [] list()
    {
        return ResPaths.toArray(new String[ResPaths.size()]);
    }

}
```

Now you can call this:

```
resourceA.setResPath("A");
resourceB.setResPath("B");
resourceA.list();
```

And it should give you paths A and B.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have public static data distinct from a class and any of its child. If it is what you want to achieve, you must instead :

- have **private** static data in each subclass
- have abstract non static getter (and optionaly setter) in abstract parent class
- have non static overriden getter (and optionaly setter) in subclasses

If it make sense, you could even have `data`, `load` and `save` in parent using generics :

```
class abstract resourceGeneric<T>
{
    T data[];

    public void load(String fileName)
    {
        //Load T data[] from getResPath()+"/"+fileName
    }

    public void save(String fileName)
    {
        //Save T data[] to getResPath()+"/"+fileName
    }

    public String [] list() // can no longer be static
    {
        return (new java.io.File(getResPath())).list(); 
    }

    public abstract getResPath();
}

class resourceA extends resourceGeneric<Double>
{
    private static ResPath = "c:/somethingA";

    public getResPath() {
        return ResPath;
    }
}

class resourceB extends resourceGeneric<Integer>
{
    private static ResPath = "c:/somethingB";

    public getResPath() {
        return ResPath;
    }
}
```

But it forces to replace the intrinsic arrays with corresponding boxing classes. If that, or if making `load` and `save` generic is not appropriate, just leave them in the concrete subclasses